# setting the x-axis when plotting convolution in matlab

Tags: matlab

i am plotting a convolution in matlab for that purpose i create 2 arrays representing the values of the functions in various points.

```
x=[1:1000];
c=[1:1000];
t = linspace(-18,18,1000);
for k=1:1000, x(k)=input(t(k));
c(k)=h(t(k));
end;

plot(conv(c,x));
```

the thing is that it plots the conv against the place of the answer in the array.
i want to plot the conv against the 'n' that will give the value. 
plotting against t,c or x from the example above does not give the righ answer. also the plot here is of length 1999.
creating a linspace of length 1999 will plot but it wont give the right answer.

any suggestions?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you actually want... please clarify, perhaps with an example with vectors short enough to print the values and demonstrate the desired output. In the meantime, try using the `'same'` arg: `conv(c,x,'same')`

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, let me clarify, when you conv 2 functions you get a new function. the problem in matlab is that you conv 2 vectors so the answer is also a vector. i want to plot the result function according to it variable, i mean the x axis should represent the variable and not the place in the vector.

Comment: @Anton.P It is still difficult to understand what you actually want to do. Perhaps you mean that the `x`-axis should be the independent variable values rather than the vector indices. Then you should create a vector of the independent variable values, say `tau`, and the use `plot(tau,conv(c,x))`. How to form the vector `tau` depends on the "physical" meaning of the functions represented by `c` and `x`.